# Multiple background image change on cursor position

Tags: jquery, cursor, background-image, rollover

How do I write jquery code to achieve this affect?

https://ferminguerrero.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Just a mousemove and a change of background image. Super irritating and epilepsia-inducing